# If I don't save prewritten string to variable, is it still in memory?

Tags: c++, string, memory

I am wondering what is happening, if I have piece of code like this:

```
std::string var1 = "Something";
"Something else";
```

Obviously I have one variable of type std::string named "var1", but I don't know if the other string I don't save to any variable is still somewhere in memory.

Basically I am working with SQL and I have one statement, that will be called only once when database will be created. So I am wondering if I should make

```
const std::string query = "statement";
```

somewhere in header file, or just use the "statement" as argument right away. I like it more the first way, because then, if ever needed, I can reuse the string.

I understand it is only few bytes and it does not really matter, I'd just like to know what is going on in memory.

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok just to make it more clear.
If I call method:

```
sql.Execute("statement");
```

Is the literal value "statement" saved somewhere in the memory for the whole life of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal value are expressions, one of the "smallest" form of expressions. And all expressions can be used as statements (by just adding the statement terminator `;`). So on its own

```
"Something else";
```

is a valid statement. It doesn't do anything useful, and should be optimized away by all but the dumbest compilers.

---

Now if your code looked like this instead

```
std::string var1 = "Something"    // Note that there's no semicolon here
"Something else";
```

that would be translated as

```
std::string var1 = "Something" "Something else";
```

And that will be parsed as string-literal concatenation and be compiled as

```
std::string var1 = "SomethingSomething else";
```

---

As for if string literals are stored in memory, yes they are. A string literal is stored as a constant array of characters (including the string null terminator).

The life-time of these arrays is the life-time of the program itself, they have static [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and pointers to elements of these array will always be valid.

Also note that compilers are allowed to combine storage for string literals. So if you have the same literal being use in multiple places, the compiler is allowed to store only a single copy of the string.

Comment: Nice info, it is just a little bit off the question. I mean, you said the compiler should get rid of it. But I wanted to know what if it does not, or as now in edited question, the string is being used somewhere.

Comment: @ligazetom It wasn't really clear until your recent edit I would say.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that.